# SELECT from a collection with GWT + App Engine + JPA

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jpa, spring-roo

Is it possible to search for entities where a Collection field contains a specific value?

For example if I have an entity named Item and it contains a Collection field named categories.

```
public class Item {

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<String> categories = new HashSet<String>();

}
```

So what I want to do is to select every item that contains the category "blue".

I tried the following queries:

SELECT o FROM Item AS o WHERE o.categories = :category

SELECT o FROM Item AS o WHERE o.categoriesKeys = :category

SELECT o FROM Item AS o WHERE :category MEMBER OF o.categories

But it doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. What exception do you get? Include it in your question, with the stacktrace.

Comment: Your annotations are wrong. You cannot have @ManyToMany on a field storing a *String*. It has to be a relation, how can the String know about the Item otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

this is wat you need: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-filtering

Comment: Why would he "need" that ? when he is using GAE and its implementation of JPA, and you refer to some non-standard feature of some other implementation of JPA.